# Basic Quadratic formula calculator shell script trouble

Tags: linux, bash, shell, math

This is my very first shell script for a Unix class, this is one of the scripts I hope to submit for my final. However there are a few kinks I cannot seem to clear up, it seems to be arithmetic operation errors, and I can't seem to figure it out. Please be kind! thank you so much for your time.

```
lightgreen=`echo -en "\e[92m"
echo What are the values of a, b \& c?

LIGHTRED=`echo -en "\e[101m"

echo a value:
read a


echo b value:
read b

echo c value:
read c

discrim=$(($b**2 - 4*$a*$c))

sqrtd=$((sqrt($discrim) | bc ))

echo test $sqrtd


echo ${lightgreen}The discriminant is:${discrim}

#xone=$((( -$b + sqrt$discrim) / (2 * $a) | bc ))
#xtwo=$((( -$b - sqrt$discrim) / (2 * $a) | bc ))

xone=$((echo (-1*$b + sqrt($discrim)) / (2*$a) | bc ))
xtwo=$((echo (-1*$b - sqrt($discrim)) / (2*$a) | bc ))

echo ${lightgreen}The discriminant is:${discrim}

#if [$discrim -lt 0 ]
#       echo $LIGHTRED There are no real solutions.
#
#
#
echo The two solutions are $xone $xtwo
```

I have tried to mess with the syntax a good amount, I'm not sure if it's the parentheses that mess me up or the sqrt function, I have tried to incorporate  | bc but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You're confusing the syntax for getting bash to do math -- `$((someformula))` -- with the syntax for getting `bc` to do math -- `$(echo someformula | bc)`. `$(( ))` does bash math, while `$( )` runs commands (like `bc`) and captures their output. bash's can't do more than basic integer math, so you need to use `bc` pretty much everywhere.

Comment: It would help if you'd post error messages for each thing you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hesitate to call `man bash`, `man bc` manual pages.

Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your shell scripts.
Shellcheck also exists on command line and in Visual Studio Code with extension.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# The first line is very important to now the name of the interpreter

# Always close " , ' , or ` sequences with same character
# Do not use old `...` syntax, replaced by $(...)
# Here, use $'...', to assign value with \... sequences
lightgreen=$'\e[92m'
lightred=$'\e[101m'
normal=$'\e[0m'
# It's better to put phrase between "..." or '...'
echo "What are the values of a, b & c?"


# Use read -p option to specify prompt
# Use read -r option to not act backslash as an escape character
read -p "a value: " -r a
read -p "b value: " -r b
read -p "c value: " -r c

# With bash only, it's only possible to use integer values
# discrim=$(($b**2 - 4*$a*$c))
# use bc instead
discrim=$(bc -l <<<"$b^2 - 4*$a*$c")

# The syntax:
#    bc <<<"..."
# is equivalent to:
#    echo "..." | bc
# but without pipe (|)

# Close the color change with normal return
echo "${lightgreen}The discriminant is: ${discrim}${normal}"

if [[ "${discrim:0:1}" == "-" ]]; then

    echo "${lightred}There are no real solutions${normal}"
    # ... complex ...

else

    sqrtd=$(bc -l <<<"sqrt($discrim)")
    echo "sqrt($discrim)=$sqrtd"

    xone=$(bc -l <<<"(-1*$b + $sqrtd) / (2*$a)")
    xtwo=$(bc -l <<<"(-1*$b - $sqrtd) / (2*$a)")

    echo "The two solutions are: $xone and $xtwo"

fi
```